# VS2013: We couldn't get your developer license for 8.1, error 0xC0020017

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to start debug my application from visual studio 2013 (v12). `DEBUG---> START Debug` but i am getting the following error message everytime(before this i got the first two screns see below, i accepted the two, but i end up in third screen), not able to debug, Please help me in this. thanks in advance for any help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look here for help from a MS employee.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2013/07/30/in-case-you-get-this-we-couldn-t-get-your-developer-license-for-windows-8-1-preview-our-server-is-unavailable-right-now-please-try-again-later.aspx

Comment: thanks for the help. Do you want me to reinstall the VS2013? i tried with powershell commands "Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration", same result

Comment: Sounds like his answer was wait, try again. If it still fails he says to reinstall the whole environment. Ridiculous, but that was what he said had to be done, and he does work at MS...